# NoMethodError: undefined method `size' for true:TrueClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j, rake, graph-databases

I am trying to install neo4j server in [my RoR-Neo4j Application](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/asset_portal/tree/sitepoint) using [the following guide](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/asset_portal/tree/sitepoint#welcome-sitepoint-readers).

In the step **4. Install Neo4j: rake neo4j:install[community-latest]** I get the following error:

```
$ rake neo4j:install[community-latest]
Retrieving latest version...
Latest version is: 2.2.7
Installing Neo4j-community-2.2.7 environment: development

HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\AppEvents
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Console
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Control Panel
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Environment
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\EUDC
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Keyboard Layout
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Network
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Printers
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Software
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\System
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `size' for true:TrueClass

Tasks: TOP => neo4j:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

The stack trace:

```
 C:\Users\<User>\rorapps\asset_portal>rake neo4j:install[community-late
st] --trace
** Invoke neo4j:install (first_time)
** Execute neo4j:install
Retrieving latest version...
Latest version is: 2.2.7
Installing Neo4j-community-2.2.7 environment: development

HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\AppEvents
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Console
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Control Panel
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Environment
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\EUDC
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Keyboard Layout
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Network
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Printers
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Software
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\System
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `size' for true:TrueClass
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/neo4j-core-5.0.7/lib/neo4j/tasks/neo4j_server
.rake:121:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_lev
el'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling
'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
C:/Ruby22/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => neo4j:install
```

My Environment is:

- Windows 7 (x64)
- ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295)
  [i386-mingw32]
- gem version: 2.5.0

Comment: What is the full stack trace? Run the command again with `--trace` as indicated by the above output.

Comment: @aceofbassgreg I added the output --trace

Comment: Hi!  Sorry, I haven't been able to continually test the rake tasks in Windows, sadly.  In this case it's trying to check to see if you have admin access (see here: https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j-rake_tasks/blob/master/lib/neo4j/rake_tasks/windows_server_manager.rb#L63 ).  It looks like it's returning `true` when the code is expecting something with a `size` method.  I'm not really sure if `true` is saying that you have admin access or just that the command ran successfully...

Comment: If you want, you can also skip that step and install Neo4j from the Neo4j website: http://neo4j.com/download/   In version 2.3 there's a nice download which lets you run it as an app.  That would replace steps 4 & 5 and then the rake tasks from the app (like in step 6) should still work

Comment: Thanks @BrianUnderwood I also suspected I didn't have admin access, but after trying to run the command in c:\sites path I moved the app to c:\Users\<My User>\rorapps, run again `rake neo4j:install` command and the output was the same

Comment: I don't think it's so much as a permissions issue as checking the registry that your user is an admin.  I would definitely install Neo4j from http://neo4j.com/download/

Comment: @BrianUnderwood despite rake aborted apparently neo4j is installed. I checked and found all neo4j stuff, for example `C:\Users\<USER>\rorapps\asset_portal\db\neo4j\development\conf\neo4j.properties` and `C:\Users\<USER>\rorapps\asset_portal\db\neo4j\development\bin\Neo4j.bat`. It could you give a clue. After all I'll follow your recomendation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, great, thanks!  If you want you can try running it from the `.bat`.  I think it would be `Neo4j.bat start`.